# Turn off Autowiring for Spring @Service

Tags: java, spring, service, autowired

I have a custom annotation that is declared as a Spring managed Service:

```
@Service
public @interface MyServiceAnnotation {
    // my service url
    String url();
}

The above declaration enables my services to be autowired as Spring Managed beans.
@MyServiceAnnotation(url="/path/serviceLocation")
public class SomeService {
   doWork();
}
```

However, there are certain services that have their bean definitions in an `applicationContext.xml`. Adding the `@MyServiceAnnotation` to such beans makes them both Autowiring enabled, as well as inject dependecy through the xml file.

Due to issues related to legacy code, I don't want to remove the xml bean definitions and make them all autowired.

So, is there a way in which I could turn off autowiring in this case, and still use `@MyServiceAnnotation`? Ideally I would like to have the `@Service` annotation on `MyServiceAnnotation`, the existing services would still use the `@MyServiceAnnotation` but would get their dependencies injected based on the xml. All the new services would be autowired without the xml bean definitions.

One possible approach is to create `NonSpringManagedMyServiceAnnotation` that is same as `MyServiceAnnotation`, but without the `@Service` annotation on it. The downside of this is that I'd have to duplicate rest of the code from `MyServiceAnnotation`, which I don't want to.

Comment: You are confusing two different topics - **autowiring** has nothing to do with your question. What you want is to suppress **bean definition registration** done by **component scan**.

Comment: My question was to keep bean definition and suppress component scan in one scenario, and keep component scan in the other...The exclude-filter seems to be a reasonable solution in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one approach, may not be that optimal though. I am assuming you would have specified a `component-scan` tag in your xml to scan the classes having the Spring stereotype annotations, these tags support a `exclude-filter` sub-tag to ignore specific patterns. If the files that you specify follow a specific pattern(specific packages, specific names etc) then you may simply be able to specify this sub-tag to ignore classes holding your annotation.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage">
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression=".*ToBeIgnoredNaming"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to maintain separation of concern.

Adding `@Service` on your annotation makes it a de facto Spring service : since this is not the behavior you want, you may simply have a simple `@MyAnnotation` (with url property) on each services (legacy and new).
Then you add Spring's `@Service` annotation on each new service to enable bean registration by annotation.

Comment: Please don't mix *autowiring* and *bean definition registration* (via component scanning) terms like the OP.

Comment: Rewriting post without doing a full read is a real shame... Thanks for the comment. Fixed to avoid people confusion.